# can we make the jquery syntax easier?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am studying jQuery right now, however, I felt really uncomfortable with the syntax.
For example, when we declare a jquery object, we have to use like

> $("p") , $(".class") or $("#id")

but why not

> $p , $.class or $#id

is that a reason that we have to use it like $("something")?
or if we can make a js file to make the syntax easier for everybody?

Thanks.

Comment: `$` is a function.. How do we call a function ?

Comment: uh, what happens if you have italic tags in your html? now `$i` isn't available for the standard `for($i = ....)` loop, or your loop now trashes all of the $i jquery objects. littering your variable name space with randomish variable names is a bad idea.

Comment: Sure you can! You just have to rewrite Javascript.......

Comment: Before 'studying' jQuery, better study js or programming in general first!

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask [The jQuery Team](https://jquery.org/team/) about this?

Comment: guys I understand how it works, I am just wondering if we can write a makeup package to simplify it.

Comment: It is simple. It's your mentality that is ruining web development. All these billions of one-off packages trying to simplify a problem that doesn't exist.

Just learn it.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, things wrapped in quotation marks are known as **strings**. A string is a series of letters, typically like a word, a sentence, etc. It's a common way of communicating through code and in real life.

jQuery is using a magical function of its own design represented by **$**. Functions have arguments, which is basically asking for something. In real life, you'd say "I want... a soda." So in code that would be something like 
    `i_want("soda")`. You have to wrap it in quotation marks because it's a string.

So in jQuery, the reason you can't shortcut that is because you're telling jQuery what you want to access.

`p` represents a paragraph tag on the document.

`.class` represents an element containing the tag "class"

`#id` represents an element with the ID "id"

So when I write `$("p")`, that's like saying `I want... p` and then you do something with it. Like `$("p").fadeOut()` will fade out all paragraph elements.

It's just the way code, and communication, works in general.

Answer (score 0):

This does not make the syntax easier. `$p`, `$` are two different variables, and `$#id` is an invalid variable name.

The syntax is `$('#id')`, or `jQuery('#id')`, because you are calling the jQuery function, aliased as the variable `$` with one argument. In the jQuery library this means that you want a set of elements that have that specific property.